# Summing list: Skip first even number

Tags: python

I am trying to sum a list but skip the first even number and then continue adding the rest of the list including the rest of the even numbers but I can't seem to get it quite right.

```
list = [-3, -7, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] 
def sum_num(num_list):
    sum = 0
    for i in num_list:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            continue
        sum += i
    return sum 
print sum_num(list)
```

Either I sum none of the even numbers or all of them. How do I make it so it just skips the first even number?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want zero to count as even?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Zero is an even number.

Comment: @AngieHernandez If my answer or another solved your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer, so your question can be marked as *solved*. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you!!! Got it. I wasn't expecting 0 to be considered an even # so I thought I was still doing it wrong haha

Comment: @AngieHernandez, it was also mentioned in a comment on my answer that you should rename `sum` to be `total` or some other name that doesn't have the same name as a built-in function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `if` statement to only succeed once.

```
def sum_num(num_list):
    total = 0
    once = False
    for i in num_list:
        if i % 2 == 0 and not once:
            once = True
            continue
        total += i
    return total
```

After it skips the first even, your Boolean `once` will be True, causing the `if` conditional to fail for successive evens.

Answer (score 3):

You can also take advantage of `itertools.takewhile` for this, eg:

```
from itertools import takewhile

def sum_num(num_list):
    it = iter(num_list)
    before_first_even = takewhile(lambda L: L % 2 != 0, it)
    return sum(before_first_even) + sum(it)

data = [-3, -7, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
result = sum_num(data)
# 17
```

This creates an iterator over `num_list` and consumes that to calculate the sum until the first even number... then `it` is left with the remainder of the list (excluding the first even number), so we add the sum of those and return the value... This avoids keeping a variable around to check if we've seen an even value or not yet...